# Monitor SQL table for when X has passed

Tags: c#, sql-server

Say I have list of subscribers in a database table in sql server.  They all have different rollover dates and therefor I have a column called RolloverDate.

At the moment I have Quartz.Net task that runs every 5 minutes checks if the rolloverdate has passed and performs the necessary functions.

Is there a better way to do this?  Seems pretty inefficient to have to run a task every 5 minutes to check this.  What are other way are their to monitor when X has passed in sql server?

Comment: Do you have the Express version of SQLServer?

Comment: Running Azure SQL.

Comment: It's not an uncommon approach to have a scheduled service/app that does exactly this type of work.  Does it need to be every 5 minutes, or can you run it nightly?  If it needs to be 5 minutes then... 5 minutes it is. (I'm not aware of other ways that don't stem off this concept, really).  I sometimes have one that runs every 10 seconds or so and checks a "schedule" to see which items need to be checked on this iteration.

Comment: I think that it strongly depends on what you need to do on RolloverDate. If you only need to change some data in your database, and this data is needed only - for example - at the time of the next query, you can think of writing some sort of trigger on SELECT or other operations, to do your modifications just in time. Otherwise, I think old school scheduled activity is the only solution. If you have the full version of SQLServer I think you can schedule operation with some sort of maintenance plan, but I don't know Azure SQLServer.

Comment: A check every 5 minutes is perfectly fine - depending of course on how the checking code is done.